# Is it possible to register a top-level intent in the Mirror API?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

Example "top-level actions" would be "Google," "take a picture," etc.

Is it possible using the Mirror API to register a custom top-level event? "OK Glass, crunchify me."

A secondary question I have is if it's possible to take user speech. Using the "OK Glass, Google" example, the user says a query that Google takes and acts on. Is it possible to capture that for your custom action using the Mirror API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not yet possible with the Glass client nor the Mirror API. However, there is already a filed [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=6) that you can follow to get updates on the progress.

Comment: Thank you. I would say this is a very crucial feature for the API to have before it hits 1.0.

Comment: For the time being you can do voice recognition for reply commands on cards. It isn't a nice UX, but it is better than nothing: https://developers.google.com/glass/menu-items#built-in-menu-items

Answer (score 1):

You can do that right now only if you both root the device (voiding your warranty) and activate what they call "Lab experiments". More specifically one called "Native App Voice", which enables you via AndroidManifest.xml of a native APK deployed to the Glass to enable a voice shortcut on the ok,glass menu to launch an intent to your app.

See: https://gist.github.com/zhuowei/5624527