# Initiating an app manually

Tags: google-mirror-api

Is it possible for the user to initiate interaction with glassware, rather than responding to cards that appear unsummoned? I plan to create an app that will only be useful in situations the user identifies.

I combed the documentation some and didn't find anything describing this, but it seems necessary.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075920/is-it-possible-to-register-a-top-level-intent-in-the-mirror-api and the related open issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=6

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **Pinned** TimelineItem 
https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline

set isPinned to true and the card will appear on the left of the home screen. Users can then initiate your app functionalities through that card's custom actions.

Answer (score 0):

A user can initiate interaction by tapping/using heads up to get to the OK GLASS prompt, then swiping to a card inserted by the Glassware, then tapping on the card, then tapping on an action. They can also share various items to contacts inserted by the Glassware. See the documentation on subscribing to user notifications:
https://developers.google.com/glass/about#subscribing_to_timeline_notifications